# Perl 6 assignment hyper operator for nested list doesn't work as expected

Tags: raku

Hello I'm trying to use the *assignment hyper operator* in `Perl 6` https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#Hyper_operators

```
﻿my (@one, @two) «=» (<1 2 3>,<4 5 6>);
say @one;
say @two;
# Prints nothing (empty array)

# Expected behaviour:
@one=<1 2 3>;
@two=<4 5 6>;
say @one;
say @two;
# Prints [1 2 3] and [4 5 6]
```

How to make the *assignment hyper operator* operate correctly? Thanks.

Comment: Per the doc, hyperops cycle thru the elements of a list/array pointed to by the hyper symbol (i.e. a list on the left if `«op...` is used, and on the right if `...op»` is used) if it's shorter than the other list. But the arrays on the left are *completely empty*, so there are *zero* elements to cycle thru, so the assignments all disappear into the great bit bucket in the sky.

Comment: Thank you for the comment and clarification. It looks like the use of hyper operator for the task of assignment was not suitable for the nested list. It's apperantly caused by the `=` operator's inability to do the *assignment* if it's assigning a list. Fortunately, the zip operator as a meta operator operated as expected.

Comment: Hi @Romario. It's not suitable if a target list has no elements, which rules out its use for *initialization*, and thus your example, but it's fine for *assignment*, including to nested lists, if *cycling* is desired and/or *autovivification* / *autoextending* isn't. Thus, for example, `my (@a, @b); @a[2] = @b[2] = Nil; (@a, @b) «=» (<1 2 3>, <4 5 6 7>); say @a, @b;` displays `[1 2 3][7 5 6]`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You were close. Just a little bit further in the docs down we find

*The zip metaoperator (which is not the same thing as Z) will apply a given infix operator to pairs taken one left, one right, from its arguments.*

So

```
my (@one, @two) Z= <1 2 3>, <4 5 6>;
```

Here's a benchmark, running on the current developer build. It compares the "magic" variant above with two sequential assignments.

```
use v6;
use Benchmark;

my %results = timethese(100000, {
    "magic" => sub { my (@one, @two) Z= <1 2 3>, <4 5 6> },
    "plain" => sub { my @one = <1 2 3>; my @two = <4 5 6> },
});

say ~%results;

# magic   1569668462 1569668464 2 0.00002
# plain   1569668464 1569668464 0 0
```

Comment: I assume this is a golf.  From a performance point of view, `my @one = <1 2 3>; my @two = <4 5 6>` would be orders of magnitude faster.  I'm just saying: Perl 6 has many features, but you don't have to use all of them all of the time  :-)

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen Actually, there is no significant difference. See above.

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen Basically, my concern was not performance but rather do the assignment in an elegant way.This way of assignment is *code-wise* scalable i.e. you can do the assignment of many variables in one, concise step. Of course that depends on the view of the programmer, too.

Comment: @Holli feels to me there is an issues with the Benchmark module: `for ^100000 { my (@one, @two) Z= <1 2 3>, <4 5 6> }; say now - INIT now` says 1.25 seconds for me, and `for ^100000 { my @one = <1 2 3>; my @two = <4 5 6> }; say now - INIT now` say 0.12 seconds.  So that's a factor of 10 difference in my book.

Comment: It's more like a factor of 7 on my system, but yeah.